# Combining subsequent elements of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as following:

arr1 = CP-en,AR-es,CP-en,BE-fr,CP-en,CZ-cs

How do I combine the array's subsequent elements so I get the following result:

result = CP-en+AR-es, CP-en+BE-fr, CP-en+CZ-cs

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need split your array into chunks (2 element per chank), for example by indexing like this:

```js
const resultIndex = Math.floor(index / 2)
```

`index` here is ininitial array index, `resultIndex` - new index of current element (chunk index actually).

2. Join them as you wish using [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
result.map(chunk => chunk.join('+'))
```

**Full code:**

```js
const arr = [ 'CP-en', 'AR-es', 'CP-en', 'BE-fr', 'CP-en', 'CZ-cs' ]
const result = []

for (let index in arr) {
  const resultIndex = Math.floor(index / 2)
  if (!result[resultIndex]) result[resultIndex] = []
  result[resultIndex].push(arr[index])
}

console.log(result.map(chunk => chunk.join('+')))
```